# Why `?` is displayed instead of non-english chars under cPanel? But not under localhost nor DirectAdmin? Using codeigniter and UTF-8. NO mysql used

Tags: html, utf-8, character-encoding, cpanel, non-english

I first created a simple HTML page that uses `UTF-8` as its character encoding.

Then I copied the HTML content to a view in codeigniter and it was still ok (I had used non-english characters that was no problem as always)

I added a simple dynamic functionality (there is a contact form that emails users' feedback to site admins).

**There was still no problem at localhost.** (which is a LAMP server running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

**I have not even connected to mysql or any other DBMSs.**

But strange is that when I uploaded the app to server, only `???????` is shown instead of the Persian characters (For example `نام` (which means Name) became `???` and so so...)

Maybe I should state that I have also used session library to thank the user after his feedback, nothing else.

Note that it's the only page in the little project (it's more an under construction page) and nothing else has been used in it.

I have really no idea about where the problem comes from!

---

**UPDATE after comments**

- **Now I can see that the problem is only with cPanel. On Directadmin (and local LAMP of course) everything is normal.** I have not tested other hosting control panels.
- Both Chromium and Firefox DO understand `UTF-8` as the page's character encoding. They are both set as Auto-detect encoding.
- URL is `http://WEBSITE.COM/dmf/dynamic/` (dmf is the abbreviation of the project name!). There is nothing non-english in the URL.
- The page's code is as follows:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <title>نام وب‌سایت</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('template/css/style.css'); ?>" />
  <!-- 1. jquery library -->
  <script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>

  <!-- 2. flowplayer -->
  <script src="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.1.1/flowplayer.min.js"></script>

  <!-- 3. skin -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://releases.flowplayer.org/5.1.1/skin/minimalist.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="wrapper">
          <header>
              <h1>نام وب‌سایت</h1>
          </header>
          <section id="box-container">
              <?php
                  echo form_open('contact', "id='contact-us'");
                  echo form_fieldset('تماس با ما');
                  if ($this->session->userdata('mailsent'))
                  {
                      echo '<div>باتشکر، پیام شما ارسال شد</div>';
                      $this->session->sess_destroy();
                  }
                  echo '<input tabindex="1" id="name-in" value="نام" type="text" name="name"/>
                      <input tabindex="2" id="mail-in" value="ایمیل" type="email" name="email"/>
                      <textarea tabindex="3" id="content-in" name="message">توضیحات</textarea>
                      <input tabindex="4" id="submit" type="submit" value="ارسال" />';
                  echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
                  echo form_fieldset_close();
                  echo form_close();
              ?>

              <div id="sms-comp">
                  <h2>مسابقه پیامکی</h2>
                  <p>
                      <span id="comp-title">یک متن تستی</span>
  سامی برندگان هفته پیش
                  </p>
              </div>

              <div id="last-program">
                  <h2>دریافت آخرین برنامه</h2>
                  <div class="flowplayer">
                      <video id="my_video_1" width="212" height="126"
                          poster="<?php echo base_url('template/images/img.jpg'); ?>" controls="controls"
                          src="http://archive.org/download/Pbtestfilemp4videotestmp4/video_test.ogv" type='video/mp4'>
                      </video>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="clear"></div>
          </section>
      </div>
      <footer>
          طراحی و توسعه : <a href="http://powered-by.com/" target="_blank">پاورد بای</a>
      </footer>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```

Comment: Looks like a bug with CPanel I would report the bug.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, are you a member of cPanel team? Why do you believe that way? Have you seen that a same problem occured with cPanel?! I myself wouldn't think like you. I'm sure that there should be a problem from my own side. (It's just a feeling). But I don't really know how to track the problem! Thank you any way.

Comment: Download the file and check the encoding with a text editor. Maybe the problem is the upload method.

Comment: @tpaksu using online editors of both cPanel and DirectAdmin, I can see correct characters, and no `?`.

Comment: Ok. Can't guess anything else without seeing the result.